# How can i cancel a cron task on ignite server node?

Tags: cron, task, scheduler, ignite

I have deployed a cron task on an ignite server node , how can i find id and cancel it from another client node ? 
I just find `SchedulerFuture` has cancel method (`IgniteFuture`) . but when the client node closed and the cron task running on a server node , how can i cancel it ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You might be willing to use Comput Tasks instead that can be stopped if a client goes down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such API in Ignite, and personally I don't recommend using `ignite-scheduler`, since it is not under active development.